# Web API calling aspx in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

This is what I am trying to accomplish and can use some help.

I have a vb.net web forms asp.net 4.5 project. I want to create an API so a client can consume the service sending in some authentication params and json data. I want to authenticate the user request and then take the json data and convert it into a data table (or whatever I can use to loop through the values). JSON data structure is based of name and email.

As I am looping through the values, I want to call one of the functions defined in the aspx page. So, basically trying to call an already defined function in another project (part of the same solution, OR if I can place the web api in the same project, either way). Finally return a notification when the job is complete to the caller. I tried multiple ways of doing it and have been unsuccessful. I would prefer to have a separate web api project in C# that would call the function located inside the vb.net project. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider refactoring you code , so that dependable code will be available to 2 project i.e. web api and aspx web form.

So move all required functions/methods from aspx webform and place in separated class library, and invoke required methods from webform or web api using the newly created class library.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. Refactoring will take time and lots of testing. Is there not a way to expose certain functions from one project to another? In this particular case all my core functions are inside the app_code directory of the web forms project. I just want to call one of the functions from the web api project inside the same solution.

Comment: @Nizar , If there is no hard bound dependency in app_code classes ( e.g. it does not take from txtbox.Text where txtbox is a TextBox defined in calling classs), then you can directly move that to separate class library and invoke from 2 places.

Comment: Thanks Arindam. Although it is not exactly what I had asked but your feedback really showed me a different approach to look at the problem. I am good.